# I can not reset the static variable after clicking on the notification

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

I have 3 types of notifications. Each has its own unique ID, which I give to the server. There's also a 3 static variables that I use to count notifications. Everything is working as I need to. But when I open the program by clicking on one of the notifications and then again to collapse, comes a new notification if the counter is not reset. This is why I use a static variable. Give me as I reset? how do I access it and reset at the opening of the group notices.

```
public class GCMIntentService extends GCMBaseIntentService {
    private static int ID_CHECKIN =1;
    private static int ID_CHECKOUT =1;
    private static int ID_NEW_COMMENT =1;
    public GCMIntentService() {
        super(SENDER_ID);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String title = intent.getStringExtra("title");
        String message = intent.getStringExtra("content");
        int groupid = Integer.parseInt(intent.getStringExtra("group_id"));
        switch (groupid){
            case 1:
                generateNotification(context,title, message,groupid,ID_CHECKIN++);
                break;
            case 2:
                generateNotification(context,title, message,groupid,ID_CHECKOUT++);
                break;
            case 3:
                generateNotification(context,title, message,groupid,ID_NEW_COMMENT++);
                break;
        }
    }

    private void generateNotification(Context context, String title, String message,int groupid,int count) {

        NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(context);
        Intent intent = new Intent(context,MyActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
                | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        Notification notification   = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_gcm)
                .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.ic_stat_gcm))
                .setTicker("Новое сообщение")
                .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setContentTitle(title+": "+count)
                .setContentText(message)
                .build();
        notification.number=count;
        notificationManager.notify(groupid, notification);
    }
}
```

Comment: which  static variable you want to reset ? Does it reside in same class ? Specify it

Comment: private static int ID_CHECKIN =1;
    private static int ID_CHECKOUT =1;
    private static int ID_NEW_COMMENT =1;
these variables I want to reset at the moment when the tap the notification

Comment: reset `GCMIntentService.ID_NEW_COMMENT =0` (whatever value you want) in *generateNotification*.. what issue ?

Comment: code that I wrote works as I need to. when a message comes in the desired type its number increases. But when I click on the notification and open the program, I need to make new notice starts again from 1. For this I want to reset static variables after the notice has been opened

Comment: It must be opening any Activity. right ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66704/discussion-between-sweetwisher--and-pavel-petrashov).